How does dask handles the datasets larger than the memory?
I'm seeking guidance on efficiently profiling data using Dask.
I've opted to use Dask to lazily load the DataFrame, either from SQL tables (dask.read_sql_table) or CSV files (dask.read_csv).
I am using this code
df = dd.read_sql_table(args)
df= client.persist(df)
...
...
df[column].min().compute()
df[column].max().compute()

The reason of using persist method is that, if i don't use the persist then dask loads the data in memory on each subsequent calls on min and max, and I don't want that it takes alot of time on each call, if I uses persist, it only loads data once in memory and then subsequent calls(min, max) gets very fast.
But I am confused how does dask persist method work?
If my dataset size is 8Gb and my memory size is 4gb, Does persist method loads all the data in memory? or does it loads the only possible partitions in the memory and then uses partition swap mechanism to does the calcualtions?

From Dask documentation:

When users hold Future objects or persisted collections (which contain many such Futures inside their dask graph, typically accessible through their .dask attribute) they pin those results to active memory

Dask persist method does not spill to disk, when you use it, you must have enough RAM in your distributed cluster to store all the data. If you try to persist a dataset bigger than your memory, it will fail.
